# leibniz criterion a.n convergs

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k (k)^8}{5^k}$$

converge, absolutely converge or diverge?

What I have tried:

$$a_k=\frac{(k)^8}{5^k}$$

Then

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{k^8}{5^k} = \color{red}0$$

According to the fact that $a_n$ converges to $1/5$, I'd say the sum diverges cause the Leibniz criterion isn't fulfilled.
What would the result of leibnitz be if $a_n$ diverges? What would that mean for absolute convergence?

edit: sorry i made a mistake the 4 should be a 5

Comment: How did you come up with $1/5$?

Comment: using quotient criteron

Comment: That limit of yours is completely wrong. Check it.

Comment: edit: sorry i made a mistake the 4 should be a 5

Comment: It still is dead wrong, @user2147674: $$\frac{(k+2)^2}{5^k}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}0$$ What you probably meant is $$a_k:=\frac{(k+2)^2}{5^k}\implies\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{} \frac15\;\;??$$

Comment: sorry i mixed two examples, now it should be right

Comment: And the last edit didn't help, @user2147674 ...so no: it isn't right. Take a little more time and check what you want to write.\

Comment: Please do not replace your original question with a new question! This new question cannot be a typo or correction to your former question. It is completely different.

Comment: I'll hold off on answering until I know you've decided on which question you want to ask. To ask a different question after you've already asked one, post it as a separate question.

Comment: Ok, I dont wanted to asked two questions in one. I'm sorry but i made a mistake the first time i posted this question, because I erroniously mixed two examples. should i create a new question with the correct example or edit?

Comment: Just remember from here onward, and be careful that you post what you *mean* to post.  Check your new question again. The series does converge, by the Leibniz test. (Your limit is incorrect: $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{k^8}{5^k} = 0.$$

Comment: thank you. 
did you find that limit with l hospital?

Comment: That's one way to proceed: but note that as $k \to \infty$, $5^k$ grows (and it grows *exponetially*) far faster than $k^8$.

Comment: Monotonicity of $|a_n|$ is required!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST**, you test for absolute convergence. Any series that converges absolutely converges, period.

**Original question:** To test for absolute convergence, you test whether the following converges:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left|\frac{(-1)^k(k+2)^2}{5^k}\right| = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(k+2)^2}{5^k}$$
If so, then the series converges *absolutely.*

---

**Failing that, THEN** you check the Leibniz criteria when you have an alternating series. If it meets the criteria, it converges.

**Failing the Leibniz criteria**, the series diverges.

---

**Original posted problem:**

Note: $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(k+2)^2}{5^k} = 0$$
So by the Leibniz criteria, the series does indeed converge.

---

Regarding the updated post:  Be careful with you evaluation of limits! $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{k^8}{5^k} = 0.$$ And indeed, by the Leibniz Test, the given series does in fact converge.

Answer (score 0):

Quotient test: If $\forall n\ a_n>0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_{n+1}\over a_n}=l<1$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Leibnitz test:
If $\forall n\ a_n\ge a_{n+1}\ge 0$ (**monotonicity required!**) then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n a_n$ converges.

The series 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k (k)^8}{5^k}$$
converges by **both** tests. (quotient: $\sum\frac{k^8}{5^k}$ converges $\implies$ $\sum\frac{(-1)^k (k)^8}{5^k}$ converges)